# Return error from promise in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a problem in my current ExpressJS-Application. I use normal functions to wrap the different routes in the app, and when an error occurs, I can easily use `return next (err)` to quit the function (`return`) and call the error handler (`next (err)`).

But what do I do if there are multiple folded functions whose execution I want to prevent?

In my code, there is the base route function, in there, I multiple other functions (which are callbacks). In these callbacks, I want to be able to quit the route execution completely. Currently, `return next (err)` only quits from the current callback, but then continues to execute the route.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit: I've broken down some code to describe the problem:

```
// This function is an expressJS route
function doSomeStuff (req, res, next) {    
    var mongooseObj = new mongooseModel ({});
    mongooseObj.save (function (err) {
        if (err)
            return next (new Error ("whatever"));
        // The line above returns from the callback, the expressJS error-handler handles the error, but then the code execution continues below
    });

    // Function continues here
}
```

Comment: Your question is very fuzzy without code but if your question is about early breaking of a promise chain, then the usual choice is between exceptions and nested promises.

Comment: I know it's fuzzy, tho I am not able to provide you with any code. Throwing the error directly would be an option, but then the expressJS error handler will not take care of it, which it should. I do not have any promises, therefore there is no promise chain to break.

Comment: No, I mean throwing the exception to break out of the chain **and** catching it. But without code I'm afraid there's not much to discuss.

Comment: Then, I'd have to wrap the entire function code inside a try-catch and use the catch-block to call the real error handler, which is - in my opinion - really bad practice. It would probably work, but there has to be a better solution.

Comment: Your try/catch block isn't suited to asynchronous operations. Some example with promises: https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/messages.js#L11

Comment: Show us an actual example of your code so we can advise more specifically.  Teaching generic error handling is not something we can answer here.  Providing you specific help for some code examples you provide is something we could do well here.  Just make your code examples cover the cases you're interested in.

Comment: I added a generic code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does not interrupt your program flow! You are not returning from the `doSomeStuff`, but from the anonymous callback that you have passed to the `save`. This function is only invoked **after** the save procedure is done, and it **doesn't** halt your program flow.

Mongoose [supports promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for `save` and alike. So the proper way to solve your problem is:

```
// This function is an expressJS route
function doSomeStuff (req, res, next) {    
    var mongooseObj = new mongooseModel ({});
    var p = mongooseObj.save();
    p.then(function() {
      // Other stuff that needs to be done *after* save succeeds
    })
    .catch(function(err) { next (new Error ("whatever")); })
}
```

Comment: I knew the problem, it seems like I have not clearly stated that. I just didn't know how to solve it. This seems to work pretty well, tho I've used .then (null, function (err)). I will try switching to .catch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is good to hear :) maybe be extra elaboration might help other people who may confuse returning from a callback!

Answer (score 0):

From what I take of it, your trying to use an error thrown in a callback to return from a function that calls this callback. You should really take a look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as it'll make this process a lot easier. You can polyfill promises and use them in older versions of Node.

The way I would try to rewrite this in a promise would be:

```
    function doSomethingStuff (req, res, next) {

      return new Promise (resolve, reject) {

        var mongooseObj = new mongooseModel ({});
        mongooseObj.save (function (err) {
           if (err)
             reject (new Error ("whatever"));

           else {resolve("something")}
        });  
    }


    doSomethingStuff(params)

      .then(//return from function)
      .catch ( function (err) { return err;}
```

Writing your code like this should let you use the error from the callback to return from your main function.